# Android RelativeLayout ALIGN_LEFT not working

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a Button and a TextView. I am trying to align the button all the way to the right of the screen and then put a TextView to the left of it, but it is not working. The code below places the button in the correct place, all the way to the right, but when the TextView it is put on the screen it knocks the button off the screen and sort of replaces the TextView right where the button was. I don't understand why it's doing this?

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

Button button = new Button(this);
button.setId(12345);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutForAlignment = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutForAlignment.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
layout.addView(button, layoutForAlignment);

TextView myTextView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
myTextView.setText("Testing");
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutForAlignmentX = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();
layoutForAlignmentX.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, button.getId());
layout.addView(myTextView, layoutForAlignmentX);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should create a new RelativeLayoutParams for TextView because you are getting a params with the rule to align right of its parent (params of button).

You also have to give an id to button.

You do:

```
Button button = new Button(this);
upgradeButton.setId(12345);
```

and you should give id to a button:

```
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setId(12345);
```

Prove this code:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

Button button = new Button(this);
button.setId(12345);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutForAlignment = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutForAlignment.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
layout.addView(button, layoutForAlignment);

TextView myTextView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
myTextView.setText("Testing");
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutForAlignmentX = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutForAlignmentX.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, button.getId());
layout.addView(myTextView, layoutForAlignmentX);
```

Sorry if you don't understand something, my english isn't very good....

Comment: Thank you! Setting the ID to upgradeButton is a typo I fixed it in my main post, but the problem is I should have been creating a new RelativeLayoutParams like you said.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem is this line:

```
layoutForAlignmentX.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, myTextView.getId());
```

It should be:

```
layoutForAlignmentX.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, button.getId());
```

This way you are setting your textview at the left of your button.

Comment: No, that's a typo when posting on here. Sorry.